# Is there any command to open list of branches in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

There is a command `git.branch` in VS Code keyboards shortcuts. This command opens dialog to create new branch.

I can not find the command to open list of all branches. Is there any command for it?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yes, there is the `git: Checkout to...` command. It displays the picker including all known branches.
You can execute this command also by clicking on the current branch name displayed on the statusbar's left side.

Look for the command `git.checkout` in case you want to create a keybinding for it. 
If you add the following code to your `keybindings.json` then you will trigger the command by typing <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>:

```
{
    "key": "shift+alt+g",
    "command": "git.checkout"
}
```

Comment: Oh! I didn't notice it. Actually I was reading commands, but not commands description. When I found `git.checkout` command I was like "What? What doest git checkout in existing git project means?". Thank you very much!

Comment: Ye I know I can do it by clicking on bottom left corner, but I had shortcut for it in WebStorm. So now I want to have same behaviour in VSCode.

Comment: Yes yes I understand how to change keybindings =) do you know is it possible to import in vs code my webstorm keymap?

Comment: If the IntelliJ IDEA Keybindings extension doesn't work then no.

Comment: you can also find "keybindings" by typing CTRL+K CTRL+S  -- search for `git.checkout`

Comment: this might be the worstly named command pallet command i've come across

Answer (score 0):

You can also import you keybindings from webstorm by doing following way:
Code > Prefrences > Migrate shortcuts from ... and then install IntelliJ IDEA keybindings from Keisuke Kato